# Record a chrome tab and save as video JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, video, record

I'm trying to record a video of a chrome tab using javascript, in reasonably good quality (720p, 25fps) and download as mp4 or webm. I've looked at a few options, but none seem to be able to actually record the video, only create a mediastream, which is then closed as soon as the tab is closed. What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/streamproc/MediaStreamRecorder

Using only javascript (and not making a chrome extension) you will not be able to record the entire tab, only a media stream from webcam or video or canvas.

Comment: Thank's, I managed to just smack everything into a canvas and record that :)

Comment: The fastest way to do this is using SVG foreign object, if you don't care about cross domain images or fonts ;)